# Emulator: coreaudio: Could not initialize playback

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, core-audio

Android Studio 3.1.3

Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Mac OS X 10.13.4

Nexus 5 API 22

MediaPlayer does not work. This is error log. No sound.

```
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Could not initialize playback
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Could not set samplerate 44100
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Reason: kAudioDeviceUnsupportedFormatError
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Could not initialize playback
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Could not set samplerate 44100
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Reason: kAudioDeviceUnsupportedFormatError
9:45    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio'
9:45    Emulator: qemu-system-i386: warning: opening audio output failed
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Could not initialize playback
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Could not set samplerate 44100
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Reason: kAudioDeviceUnsupportedFormatError
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Costrong textuld not initialize playback
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Could not set samplerate 44100
9:45    Emulator: coreaudio: Reason: kAudioDeviceUnsupportedFormatError
9:45    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `dac'
```

The error occurs at Emulator startup, not at program startup.

Comment: Why haven't you shared your code?

Comment: The error occurs at Emulator startup, not at program startup.

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem. I use BOOM 3D application on my MacBook. It is an Audio Enhancer. The app uses MacBook audio output. So when I disabled the app the problem disappeared.